# Replace Laptop Battery With Power Supply

Tags: laptop, battery, power, laptop-repair, repair

I have an old Macbook Pro 2013 UK version, and it's broken. I have a feeling it's the charging circuit for the battery that's broken, and that everything else works fine. I'd like to have a go at fixing this myself. My first thought was that if I removed my laptop's battery, and connected an adjustable power supply in its stead, which supplied the same voltage to the board as the battery would, then I could at least get the thing to boot and run- just to confirm my theory. Then I can research the cost/method of replacing certain charging circuit components and decide if it's worth it.

Does anyone know of any problems that might arise from this? Would this work or would I end up breaking both the power supply and laptop (even more)?

Thanks to anyone who can advise on this!!

Comment: It's more likely that the battery is dead and needs replacement, if it's worth the price.

Comment: The laptop already has a power supply, why not just try that after disconnecting the battery?

Comment: @JamesP - it won't boot if the battery is totally dead, which after 10 years it's quite likely to be. The charger is meant to charge the battery, not power the computer. The battery provides power-smoothing too, something you'll not get from a regular switch-mode supply. Next issue would be how you figure out which of the 11 terminals coming from an MBP battery carry what voltage…

Comment: @Tetsujin The charger's purpose is to both charge the battery and power the laptop - this can be found via a search engine, but a logic question would be more efficient: if a charger isn't used to both charge the battery and power the laptop, how does the laptop remain on while the battery is charging _(charging and discharging a battery at the load required to run a laptop would result in the battery overheating continually, lowering the lifespan of the ~200 cycles batteries usually only get anyways.

Comment: @Tetsujin: I was suggesting it for the purpose of a simple way to test if the battery was the issue, not a long term solution. Although of course many people with other laptop brands using their computers plugged in all the time have been running with the batteries removed for years due to paranoia about battery wear. Maybe MacBooks are extra fragile and will explode in this scenario, I don’t know. In which case maybe trying to substitute in the DC power supply which has some completely different characteristics to the actual battery isn’t a good idea

Comment: @JW0914 - some will, some won't. Mine, a 2012, will not. - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/286211/can-macbooks-run-without-a-battery Additionally *"If the battery is removed from a MacBook or MacBook Pro, the computer will automatically reduce the processor speed. This prevents the computer from shutting down if it demands more power than the A/C adaptor alone can provide."*

Comment: Replace the battery, as for laptops, it's a required portion of the power circuit - laptops should never be used without a battery installed _(AFAIK every manufacturer explicitly states this)_. A dead battery that will not charge has an internal fault, otherwise it would charge, and it's never recommended to continue using such a battery because should the battery's onboard PCB protection circuit fail, and faulted batteries are charged, a fire will likely eventually result _(PCB schematics are proprietary, and not accessible for most products, so airing on the side of caution is recommended)_

Comment: On many laptops, the battery has *multiple* connections to the charging circuit, e.g., one wire to each cell, plus wires to a battery temperature sensor and possibly an manufacturer's identifying chip. Depending on design, the machine *might* not be able to run without a battery, or the "correct" battery. See *Unauthorized Bread*, https://craphound.com/radicalized/